# Print HTML File in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I'm printing a HTML File in a thermal printer in my WPF Application using the code below:

```
var wb = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
wb.Url = uri;
wb.DocumentCompleted += (sender, e) => wb.ShowPrintDialog();
```

but I need to remove the margin in the paper. Does anyone knows how to do that?

Also, this is the best way to print HTML file in c#?

Comment: If you can, avoid WebBrowser Control, it is poor, and has a know unmanaged memory leak bug. If your user use your Application for a week without closing it , you can expect a complain from them.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, I haven't noticed that!

Comment: I am using HiQPdf to convert html to pdf. Which than can be printed. The margins can also be adjusted during the conversion.